# Dropping dimensions in R array

Tags: arrays, r

**The problem**

Let K >= 2 and d >= 3. I have a 3-dimensional array with dimensions `c(K,K-1,d)`.

For example, if K = d = 3,

`A <- array(1:18,dim = c(3,2,3))`.

Now I want to get a (K-1) x d matrix by selecting an index along the first dimension, e.g.

`M <- A[1,,]`.

If K > 2 it works fine. But if K = 2, the second dimension is 1 and the default behaviour of R is to drop it. Hence, the following code will return a length d vector instead of a matrix.

```
K <- 2
d <- 3
A <- array(1:6,dim = c(K,K-1,d))
A[1,,]
```

I need a matrix because I want to do a matrix product.

**What I tried**

One can force R not to drop dimensions, by using the `drop` option.

```
M <- A[1,,,drop = FALSE]
dim(M)
```

But this returns a 3-dimensional array, as the first dimension is not dropped either.

I also tried to use `as.matrix`.

```
M <- as.matrix(A[1,,])
dim(M)
```

This returns a d x (K-1) matrix instead of the desired (K-1) x d matrix. Well, I could use transposition `t()` but then it wouldn't work anymore as soon as K>2. Is there an efficient way to get this work whatever the value of K?

Comment: Yes it looks like it's working, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array and explicitly specify the desired dimensions:

```
array(A[1, , ], dim=c(K-1, d))
```

Comment: Atleast for me, the `array` is a little misleading. `matrix(A[1,,], nrow=K-1, ncol=d)` would work as well I think. Also `res <- A[1,,]; dim(res) <- c(K-1, d)`